# Sql Server group by , count query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
select COUNT(mc_owner) as nbr , mc_owner
from [dbo].[full] 
where (date_reception > '01-01-2015')
group by (mc_owner)
order by nbr desc
```

this shows me

> - 20000   element1
> - 10000  element2
> - 10000  element3
> - 10000 element4

i need to have only two results element1 and others grouped in on element 
something like

> - element1 20000
> - others   30000

Thank you for helping

Comment: Those results do not match the query (which puts the count first). Before we try an answer please make your question self consistent.

Comment: And also define the criteria that define when rows are grouped under "others".

Comment: thats not the real results  i just wanted to simplify thank you for your remarque

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it with a `CASE` expression, like this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) as nbr,
    CASE mc_owner WHEN 'Element1' THEN 'Element1' ELSE `Others` END as Owner
FROM [dbo].[full] 
WHERE (date_reception > '01-01-2015')
GROUP BY CASE mc_owner WHEN 'Element1' THEN 'Element1' ELSE `Others` END
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

The idea is to provide an expression that evaluates to one of two values that you need - i.e. `'Element1'` or `Others`, depending on the value of the `mc_owner` field.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare   @tt table(name varchar(10),id int)

insert into @tt(name,id)values ('element1',2000)
insert into @tt(name,id)values ('element2',2000)
insert into @tt(name,id)values ('element3',2000)
insert into @tt(name,id)values ('element4',2000)


;WITH CTE AS
(
select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition by ID ORDER BY ID,name) RN, * from @tt 

)
select NAME,ID from CTE
where RN = 1
UNION ALL
select 'Others' as NAME,SUM(id) as ID 
from CTE
where RN >1
```